# search Auto-Complete suggestion ranking/weight

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, autosuggest

I am using elasticsearch (which is based on lucene) and got the auto-complete to work.

It allows you to add weights to rank the results. But I want to rank the results based on users previous search history. For example: If there are 2 indexes "Nevermind" and "Neverever", user#1 previously searched and selected Neverever, when he types "Neve", i want to display "Neverever" first....

Any ideas?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Indexing with weights...

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/music/song/1?refresh=true' -d '{
    "name" : "Nevermind",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
        "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
        "payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },
        "weight" : 34
    }
}
```

Comment: Its been a while...

But, how did you solve it? Did you index the user's search history?

Comment: @Lital It turns out ES does not have filtering or sorting capabilities on suggest index. (Search their github). There are roadmap items for some filter options like geo-filter etc. With current ES functionality I ended up updating the weight with epoch timestamp when a record was last viewed. But again this takes global effect rather than individual user history. It atleast helped me show popular records than stale records. You could also try suggestr with filter by index type. It depends on your domain though. Hope this helps...